# Shower is leaking water from frame

Tags: shower, leak, leaking

It has already been sealed using Silicone but there is water coming out from the metal/aluminium join near the corner. The mastic guy tried to apply clear silicone but it did not stick well and has partly come off within a week

Any suggestions please?[image]

Comment: Sealing needs the surfaces clean and dry and needs to be done on the side the water comes from.  You stop water from coming in, not from coming out.

Comment: you have lots of condensation, what are we looking at

Comment: Can you look at the video on link? https://streamable.com/7izrn1

Comment: Can i fix it using gorilla waterproof sealant tape?

Comment: It needs sealing from the other side.  Remove any old caulking/sealer and clean.

Comment: That is not a leek, it is condensation

Answer (score 0):

That situation is a collection of "Band Aides" used in attempts to solve a problem.  Non of them solved the issue/s, now you are attempting to add more.

The shower enclosure is obviously leaking. It is old. Time to replace it or at least remove it and replace it with a curtain after any mounting holes are filled and sealed.

Then you will probably find that your baseboard and possibly the flooring is damaged from the long term leak that was never repaired properly.

Do yourself a favor and repair properly. If you don't want another enclosure. go for the curtain.